# Return type for static async method

Tags: typescript

Can someone advise the correct Typescript return type for the static async method loadArray() below?

`Promise<boolean>` as shown below produces the error: "The return type of an async function or method must be the global Promise type.ts(TS1064)"

Note that I have no trouble creating correct return types for non-static async methods.

I'm using TypeScript 3.2.2.

```
class DataItemUpdate {
  type: string;
  json: {
    id: string;
    owner: string;
  }
  static async loadArray(outputForAppend: DataItemUpdate[], inputKeys: string[], typeName: string): Promise<boolean> {
    const redisMulti = redisClient.multi();
    inputKeys.forEach(keyName => {
      redisMulti.get(`${keyName}:json`);
    })
    let loaded: (string | null)[] = await redisMulti.execAsync();
    if (loaded.includes(null)) { // If any item failed to load
      return false
    } else {
      outputForAppend.push(
        ...loaded.map(jsonString => {
          return { 'type': typeName, 'json': JSON.parse(jsonString) };
        })
      )
      return true
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by removing

```js
import Promise = require('bluebird');
```

from the top of the file. That was the problem - some issue relating to TypeScript and Bluebird promises.

Answer (score 2):

There are two choices:

**Number one**

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function the return of async function is implicitly wrapped to a Promse.

So you can add `"lib": ["es2018", "dom"]` into `compilerOptions` part of the `tsconfig.json` file.

**Number two**

The definition of your function is : `static async loadArray(...): Promise<boolean>` and the type return is `Promise<boolean>`

In your code you return `false` or `true` so there is a mismatch between both.

You can resolve it:

- you change the type return of the function to `boolean`

or

- you can do `Promise.resolve([your_boolean])` or `Promise.reject([your_boolean])`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: Actually, if you don't return a promise, the value you return will automatically be wrapped in a promise.

Comment: @brunobastosg do you have a documentation about it?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: It's possible to add `"lib": ["es2018", "dom"]` into the `tsconfig.json` file

Comment: Thanks very much @mickaelw and others. I do have ```"target": "es2018"``` in my compiler options. I have now solved the problem by removing ```import Promise = require('bluebird');``` from the top of the file. That was the problem - some issue relating to TypeScript and Bluebird promises.